# can we simplify this shorthand if/else

Tags: javascript

can we simplify this more :

```
flag ? itemFailed(item, $content, "#ln", "data1") :
       itemFailed(item, $content, "#in", "data2")
```

Comment: Yes. Should you? Probably not...

Comment: Maybe `itemFailed(item, $content, flag ? "#ln" : "#in", flag ? "data1" : "data2")`

Comment: do you use the returned value?

Comment: nope there is no returned value here ,just  set of statements in the function .

Comment: Any code that takes longer to look at and understand than a simple if/else isn't worth it.

Comment: `itemFailed(item,$content,['#in','#ln'][flag|0],['#data2','#data1'][flag|0])`

Comment: @james True.I feel the same buddy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, just place the conditional in the arguments:

```
itemFailed(item, $content, flag?"#ln":"#in", flag?"data1":"data2")
```

Alternatively, if you want to evaluate the condition only once, you might want to use spread argument syntax:

```
itemFailed(item, $content, ... flag?["#ln", "data1"]:["#in", "data2"])
```

Of course, neither of those is very readable. While you could use better indentation (like in @jakemingolla's answer), your original expression is much simpler and doesn't have *that* much duplication. If you really want to avoid that though, like when the actual arguments are a bit bigger, I'd suggest to use helper variables:

```
const [hash, data] = flag // use descriptive names
  ? ["#ln", "data1"]
  : ["#in", "data2"];
itemFailed(item, $content, hash, data)
```

Comment: The second method is clever, that's the only positive thing I can say about it :)

Comment: @Barmar Agreed. I've added a third alternative that fixes the shortcomings of the second.

Comment: That's actually almost reasonable. And it serves him right that it doubles the number of lines of code.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm not fully understanding the question, but no, I do not believe you can simplify it any more. You have a single ternary expression with a single expression as the output.

You could, I guess, create a single function call with the ternary used for parameter selection, like:

```
itemFailed(
  item,
  $content,
  flag ? '#ln' : '#in',
  flag ? 'data1' : 'data2'
);
```

But I don't think that is much better.

Don't forget that simplicity and length are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this with spread syntax:

```js
function itemFailed(a, b, c, d) { console.log(a, b, c, d) }

let flag = true

let item = 'i'
let $content = 'abc'

itemFailed(item, $content, ...flag ? ["#ln", "data1"] : ["#in", "data2"])


flag = false
itemFailed(item, $content, ...flag ? ["#ln", "data1"] : ["#in", "data2"])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
itemFailed(item, $content, "#ln", flag ? "data1" : "data2")
```

Can't get much shorter than that.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but the OP has 'in' for the second one and 'ln' on the first one. Could be a typo?

Comment: @Cyberboy1551 Possibly, there are a couple other answers that have two ternary operators in them, but this actually makes it more complex and doesn't make it much shorter, if at all.

Comment: Yah, I just wanted to make sure you knew the second parameter was different, therefore, would need a ternary operator as well. Based on the other answers I'm assuming it's not a typo anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually store the function arguements in a variable and then pass the variable to your function something like this

```
var args = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
function oi(a,b,c,d,e,f){
    return {a,b,c,d,e,f};
}
oi(...args);
```